# using linq to select a column from a datatable

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

Currently I am using sql and hitting the database to populate a dropdown.

```
Dim sqlStatement = "SELECT DISTINCT IMLOCN FROM table order by IMLOCN desc"
    LocationDropDown.DataSource = DB.sql(dbSalesWeb, sqlStatement)
    LocationDropDown.DataTextField = "IMLOCN"
    LocationDropDown.DataBind()
    LocationDropDown.Items.Insert(0, "ALL")
```

DB is a custom class and sql returns a Datatable. I'd like to use linq on a datatable that already has the IMLOCN

```
 Protected Sub updateDropDowns(ByVal dt As DataTable)


    Dim location = From u In dt.Rows _
                        Select u("IMLOCN") _
                        Distinct

    LocationDropDown.DataSource = location.ToList
    LocationDropDown.DataBind()

End Sub
```

I've tried
 `dt.AsEnumerable()`
and `Dim location = From u In dt.AsEnumerable _
                            Select u.Field(Of String)("IMLOCN") _
                            Distinct`
I'd like to be able to use linq and I'd like to learn more about it

Comment: What's your question?  Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what error you get, but this query should work fine:

```
Dim qLocation = (From u In dt.AsEnumerable() _
                Select u.Field(Of String)("IMLOCN")).Distinct()
LocationDropDown.DataSource = qLocation.ToList()
LocationDropDown.DataBind()
```

Comment: with the above linq query I get the error " unable to cast object of type System.Byte to type System.string"  In the DB IMLOCN is a tiny int.  when I look in the debugger Location doesn't have any results in it.  If I switch the column to IMSTK which is a varchar in the DB Location actually has results in it, but I get the error "dataBinding System.String does not contain a property with the name IMLOCN"  but I switched and used IMSTK instead of IMLOCN, why does the debugger say IMLOCN still?

Comment: I databind the dropdown when the page is first loaded to the results from a sql query.  Is that causing problems with databinding it to the  linq results?

Comment: When I databind to the sql results earlier I am also setting the datatextfield = "IMLOCN" is that causing the string does not contain a property with the name IMLOCN error?